# Django URL issue with regular expressions

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I am new to Python, Django 1.9 and overall regular expressions. So I am trying to write something like this within urls.py

```
search/doc_name/language/?id
```

1. where `doc_name`, allow for *any name/case/length* etc. like so: `'My Fave Doc 12'`
2. where language, allow *two letters* like so: `'en'`
3. where `id`, allows *only numbers*.

This is what I have, can someone point out where I went wrong?

```
url(r'^search/[\w-]+/[a-z]{2}+/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', '....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `doc_name` doesn't allow spaces. Add a space in the character set if you want one. Make sure you put it before the dash (`[\w -]+`). If other whitespaces are allowed, used `\s` instead (`[\w\s-]+`).

Also the language would currently match any even amount of letters. Remove the `+` and leave only `[a-z]{2}`. `+` means repeat one or more times, anything is matched only once by default.

Answer (score 0):

You should really avoid to have spaces in you URL, I suggest the following:

**url format:** `/search/<doc_name>/<id>/?lang=<language>`

in **urls.py**:

```
url(r'^search/(?P<doc_name>[\w]+)/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$'), your_view)
```

in **views.py**:

```
lang = request.GET.get('lang', 'en')
doc_name = request.POST.get('doc_name')
id = request.POST.get('id')
```